# Which reflexive or intensive pronoun should I use for an unknown person (himself, herself or itself)?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, reflexives

I want to reffer to a person whose gender I don't know.

Should I say `a person himself/herself` or `a person itself`?

Two examples below:

`Reflexive`: If someone wants to kill somebody else, then do it him/herself.

`Intensive`: I need to run a mask detection, but I just need to use someone's head or face, not the person himself/herself.

Comment: Reflexive: If someone wants to kill, then do it him/herself.

Intensive: I need to run a mask detection, but I just need to use someone's head, not the person himself/herselvf

Comment: It is not uncommon to see good writers sometimes resort to _themselves_ in such cases to dodge the discomfiting _himself/herself_. But you need to fix the sentence a bit: _If someone wants to kill [somebody else], **they should** do it themselves._

Comment: Thank you. Let me edit my sentence.

 Is that normal to collocate `someone` with `themselves`. Should we also use `someone` for plural?

Comment: That's what I meant when I said _it's not uncommon to see good writers..._. It isn't strictly grammatical but _himself/herself_ could sound awkward at times.

Comment: Got it. That's great to learn these kind of things.

Comment: My fix is usually to set the subject in plural, to set up the plural pronoun.  

"If people want to kill others, they should do it themselves." 

"I need to run mask detections, but I just need to use people's heads or faces, not the people themselves."

Comment: That's great. Thanks!

Comment: _Themself_ works just fine, and is just as singular as _they_ or _them_ or _their_. And just as singular as _you_ and _your_, though not as recent a change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's "themselves" unless you want to say "himself or herself" every time.**

*A side note:* Although this is how I reference and understand referenced a person of unknown gender, there have been disputes about the usage of gender-neutral pronouns, especially in recent years. However, you would be understood using "themselves":

> **Use themselves as the reflexive/intensive pronoun** to refer to an
> indefinite gender-neutral noun or pronoun that is the subject of the
> sentence and avoid themself.

I would rather state the other voice regarding this, too:

> Although some current dictionaries, for example, The New Oxford
> Dictionary of English, state that themself has re-emerged in recent
> years when used to refer to a singular gender-neutral noun or pronoun
> ("themselves" remains the normal third person plural reflexive form),
> they label it as "rare" or "disputed" or **"not widely accepted in
> standard English"**.

The references are from [Department of Justice of Canada](https://www.justice.gc.ca/eng/rp-pr/csj-sjc/legis-redact/legistics/p1p30.html)

Answer (score 1):

Is it not correct that in standard English the masculine pronoun himself can be used when the sex of the subject is indefinite or gender-neutral?

"Should we really object to what someone calls himself?"

Comment: Are you providing an answer or asking a question?